# WSO2 ESB 5.00 server getting an OutOfMemoryError when connected to ESB analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 with WSO2 ESB Analytics on my local machine (ubuntu 14.04). I have created an API using wso2 development studio and deployed it to WSO2 server. While running both WSO2 server and analytics server on my local machine, the newly created API was called through PostMan. I'm getting correct response, but I can see following error on WSO2 ESB console.

```
Exception in thread "message-flow-reporter-0-tenant--1234" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:622)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:539)
at org.apache.synapse.aspects.flow.statistics.publishing.PublishingEvent.getObjectAsList(PublishingEvent.java:274)
at org.apache.synapse.aspects.flow.statistics.publishing.PublishingFlow.addEvent(PublishingFlow.java:43)
at org.apache.synapse.aspects.flow.statistics.util.TracingDataCollectionHelper.createPublishingFlow(TracingDataCollectionHelper.java:170)
at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.services.MessageFlowReporterThread.processAndPublishEventList(MessageFlowReporterThread.java:225)
at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.services.MessageFlowReporterThread.run(MessageFlowReporterThread.java:95)
```

When analytics server is stopped, I'm not getting that error. After getting this error, analytics server will not update with any statistics until next server restart.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this kind of error?